# Teamcity - Sonar Scanner for Msbuild "Insufficient Privilege" Error

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, teamcity

I tried to integrate Sonar Scanner for Ms Build with Teamcity. But there is problem in finish analysis step. I configured SonarQube.Analysis.xml file with sonar.login, sonar.password and sonar.host.url as it is showed on sonarqube website. But it gives error.

[SonarQube Begin Analysis Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDpbC.png)

[SonarQube Finish Analysis Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFfvC.png)

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1xQ.png)

I tried to restart server, clean caches, running msbuild on command line. And when I try to post a request to SonarQube url via postman, it was able to create project on SonarQube without codes and my credential worked well.

However, when I try to run SonarQube on Teamcity, it gives "Insufficient Privilege" error.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get this SonarQube plugin for TeamCIty?

Comment: @Peska I downloaded from https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Install+the+SonarScanner+for+MSBuild for .NET Framework v4.6+

Comment: I'm asking about this Runner Type in build step in TeamCity from your first and second print screen.

Comment: I downloaded from Sonarqube website and uploaded Teamcity as plugin. Then those steps appeared.

Comment: As far as I know there is no official SonarScanner for MSBuild plugin for TeamCity. That's why I'm asking where did you get it.

Comment: It is provided on SonarQube official website. I did not expect it as steps but it appeared after I uploaded the plugin and it is easy to use as a step instead of running msbuild on command line.

Comment: If you are using this plugin: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+plugin, then read comments at the bottom of this page: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration  "Currently this plugin doesn't support SonarQube MSBuild Runner. You can still try using this plugin (some functionality can be inaccessible) or use TC command line runner to manually start and finish the SQ Runner."

Comment: I have that plugin. But we develop projects with .net solutions so after updating C# plugin of SonarQube, it does not analyze C# codes. Also SonarQube recommends Sonar Scanner for ms build. That is why I tried to analyze our projects by it.

Comment: Try using a new user token. Check again if the user has [execute analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) rights.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thank you. It worked with token! I think teamcity does not support username password for msbuild. Could you please write this as an answer? Then I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the SonarQube steps you have to define a token for an user who has [execute analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) rights. You use this token as login; this is the preferred way (the password should be empty). See also the [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) documentation page.